# How to get IsSelectionActive for WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, css-selectors

I am trying to get `IsSelectionActive` to work with the WPF DataGrid:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <ContentPresenter />
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                            <!--<Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" Value="True" />-->
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
```

Basically, when the focus is lost for the grid, but the selection still remains, I want to apply some styling.

Unfortunately, `IsSelectionActive` throws an error that it does not exist in the WPF data grid for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IsSelectionActive is an attached property.  I think you need to use

```
<Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False" />
```

This simplified style works for me:

```
<Style x:Key="CellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False" />
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: That's it! Can you explain why do we need to use this `Selector.` while we don't need it for several properties?

Comment: @rFactor: The style is targetting a DataGridCell which has a dependency property IsSelected.  There's no IsSelectionActive property.  The Selector class (derived from ItemsControl, base class for ListBox, DataGrid etc, anything that supports selection) has the readonly attached property IsSelectionActive (as well as the attached property IsSelected etc).  So you need to specify Selector.IsSelectionActive, just like you use Grid.Row="1" which is an attached property defined by Grid, not a property of the item in the grid.